# Twitter4j: search for keywords within a hashtag

Tags: java, twitter, filter, twitter4j, hashtag

I'm working on an app using Twitter4j.
I'm trying to import tweets with a certain hashtag (ex: weather)
Then, I want to categorize the Tweets with that hashtag, by searching for keywords.

For example:
Some of the Tweets imported could be

```
- OMG, I hate this rain #weather
- This sunshine makes me feel so happy #weather
- Such strange #weather! One moment it rains, the next the sun shines. Confusing!
- Rain makes me sad #weather
- I love the sunshine! #weather
```

Then, I want to categorize these tweets as:

```
- hate, Confusing, sad,... are negative 
- happy, love,... are positive
```

PositiveTweets would be:

```
- This sunshine makes me feel so happy #weather
- I love the sunshine! #weather
```

NegativeTweets would be:

```
- OMG, I hate this rain #weather
- Such strange #weather! One moment it rains, the next the sun shines. Confusing!
- Rain makes me sad #weather
```

So, `NegativeTweets=3` and the `PositiveTweets=2`

Can anyone help me with this or point me towards something similar?

Answer (score 6):

You can query for the #weather hashtag, then separate the tweets into separate lists based on whether or not they contain any of the keywords you designate for either good or bad weather.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws TwitterException {
    List<Tweet> goodWeather = new ArrayList<Tweet>();
    List<Tweet> badWeather = new ArrayList<Tweet>();

    Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
    System.out.println("Fetching Weather Data...");

    // get the 1000 most recent tweets tagged #weather
    for (int page = 1; page <= 10; page++) {
        Query query = new Query("#weather");
        query.setRpp(100); // 100 results per page
        query.setPage(page);
        QueryResult qr = twitter.search(query);
        List<Tweet> qrTweets = qr.getTweets();

        // break out if there are no more tweets
        if(qrTweets.size() == 0) break;

        // separate tweets into good and bad bins
        for(Tweet t : qrTweets) {
            if (t.getText().toLowerCase().contains("happy") ||
                t.getText().toLowerCase().contains("love")) {
                goodWeather.add(t);
            }

            if (t.getText().toLowerCase().contains("sad") ||
                t.getText().toLowerCase().contains("hate")) {
                badWeather.add(t);
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Good Weather: " + goodWeather.size());
    for (Tweet good : goodWeather) {
        System.out.println(good.getCreatedAt() + ": " + good.getText());
    }

    System.out.println("\nBad Weather: " + badWeather.size());
    for (Tweet bad : badWeather) {
        System.out.println(bad.getCreatedAt() + ": " + bad.getText());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want to do is `Sentiment Analysis` to see how many of the tweets you retrieve are positive and how many are negative, right?  A good start would be to look into `SentiWordNet` it has a lot of words already stored with their polarities of how positive or negative a word is, it's only a text file containing all of this data. You would need to parse it and store the data in some data structure.  Once you have all this done then you simply need to scan the tweets and match the words and get the scores and then tag the tweets.  It's not as hard as it sounds, get searching on `SentiWordNet` first.  I believe this is the better way to go, as it will help you more in the long run :)

hope this helped